# WWW::Mechanize field methods

Tags: perl, mechanize, textfield

What is the difference between

```
$mech -> field($name, $value)
```

and

```
$mech -> set_fields($name => $value)
```

and why do they both exist? It seems like they each set the field named `$name` to `$value`.

Comment: Sometimes the same action is possible in two different ways. I wouldn't worry about it overly - it's often a result of someone trying to write code to support two different paradigms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$mech -> field($name, $value)
```

field() only lets you set one name at a time.  But

```
$mech -> set_fields($name => $value, $name2 => $value2,... $nameN => $valueN)
```

...set_fields() allows you to set multiple names at the same time.

That's not really such a big deal because you could always use the first one in a loop:

```
my @data = (
    first => 'A',
    last  => 'B',
    age   => 22,
    #possibly 100,000 other name/value pairs
);

my($name, $value);

while(@data) {
   ($name, $value) = splice(@data, 0, 2);
   $mech->field($name, $value); 
}
```

...but it's more convenient to write:

```
$mech->set_fields(@data);
```